# How can we make this statement more valid?

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic, attributes

' the order item to be deliverd in ' + ''+orderData.orders[i].delivery_address.delivery_pincode+''+''

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tmprakash3/y517xq2L/1/

Comment: Give some background on what you're trying to achieve and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You try to set the source before the element even exists. Even before you append the table to the container
2. You have duplicate IDs that will never work. Why not just set the src directly?
3. Use a class instead of inline style
4. Never bother having a div in a cell - EITHER do not have a table OR have the class on the cell

```js
const orrArray = [ 
{"pid":1, "product_name":"n1","product_cost":1,"quantity":1 },
{"pid":2, "product_name":"n2","product_cost":2,"quantity":2 },
{"pid":3, "product_name":"n3","product_cost":3,"quantity":3 },
{"pid":4, "product_name":"n4","product_cost":4,"quantity":4 },
]

let table = []
const src = '/kernel/imageload?table=cat_images;key1=PID_thumb;key2=PID_thumb;key3=-100_thumb';
$.each(orrArray, function(index, value) {
  var newSrc = src.replace(/PID/g,value.pid);
  table.push(`<tr><td class="img-holder"><img src="${newSrc}" class="img" /></td>
    <td class="prod-title-col"><h3 class="prod-title">${value.product_name}</h3></td>
    <td class="prod-price-col"><h3 class="prod-cost">&#163;${(value.product_cost * value.quantity)}</h3></td>
  </tr>`);
});
$("#tb").append(table.join(""));
```

```css
.img-holder img {object-fit: contain; height: 60px; width: 60px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
  </tbody>
</table>
```